# How does Array.Reverse() reverses a string without assignment?

Tags: c#

How does Array.Reverse() method reverse an array of word without any assignment?

Comment: Have you learned about pointers yet? I'm aware that C# doesn't explicitly have pointers, but do you know the concept behind them?

Comment: Solve it by hand on paper, step by step, and show your work (with words or pictures, whichever is easiest for you).  Sort of like you would with a math problem, except you're more or less executing a program on paper.  Tricky array logic like this is much easier to understand when you use that strategy.

Comment: It might be worth a read here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpstringreversal.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method modifies the array itself, so you can use it in its reversed state right away; there is no need to return a copy of the array to assign back to your existing variable. Arrays are *reference types*, so their contents can be modified in place without reassigning.

See the [MSDN entry for `Array.Reverse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932.aspx), and [arrays in the C# programming guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx).

Comment: where is it get stored while reversing takes place.

Comment: It is unlikely to get stored in its entirety while getting reversed. Imagine the word is on a piece of paper and you only have a pair of scissors. How would you reverse a word?

Comment: @user1070662, the array itself is stored on the heap, but let's not worry about that. The array is a reference type. All you pass into the method is the *reference* to where the array is. You pass it an address. The code then acts upon the object (your array) at that address. It's like having your house painted professionally. You do not send your house to the painter, you simply tell him where your house is. Your house is painted in place. Similarly, the array is reversed in place.

Comment: Does the Array.Reverse() method changes the memory location?

Answer (score 3):

Think of your RAM as a whole bunch of drawers in a huge cabinet. Let's say each drawer can hold one letter of your word. If you want to reverse your word, would you make a copy of each letter in another location in your cabinet, or would you just keep swapping letters from their original positions as necessary? `Array.Reverse()` uses the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

core method:

```
 while (num < num2)
        {
            object obj3 = array.GetValue(num);
            array.SetValue(array.GetValue(num2), num);
            array.SetValue(obj3, num2);
            num++;
            num2--;
        }
```

two ways swap

Comment: This raises more questions than it answers for the OP, who's a beginner to programming. A bit of explanation at each step would make this answer more valuable.